# Console.log Array value in Object

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object.

```js
let obj = {
  'app': ['placementId'],
  'app2': ['siteId'],
  'app3': ['channel_id'],
};

function search(y) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter((x, id, arr) => {
    console.log(obj['app'][0]) // returns 'placementId'
    if (x == y) {
      return obj[y][0] // returns ['app']
    }
  })
};

let result = search('app');
console.log(result);
```

I don't really understand why the function returns ['app'] and not placementId, like it did in the console.log statement. Thank you!

Comment: Because that's how [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Filter` doesn't work like you think it does. `return obj[y][0]` does not return `['app']` as your comment says. `.filter` does.

Filter takes an array, and will keep or discard every element inside, depending if you return `true` or `false` (or at least something "truthy" or "falsy"). Here, you start with `['app', 'app2', 'app3']` and inside the filter, you `return obj['app'][0]`, which is `['placementId']`. This something "truthy" (meaning, not false/null/undefined), so `'app'` is kept, and the rest is discarded. The starting array was `['app', 'app2', 'app3']` and the filtered array is `['app']`.

What you are trying to do can simply be done this way :

```js
let obj = {
  'app': ['placementId'],
  'app2': ['siteId'],
  'app3': ['channel_id'],
};

const search = y => obj[y][0];

let result = search('app');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have returned `obj[x]` or `obj[y]`, as when you pass the `Obj[key]` it gives out value. You are trying to give wrong output.

```js
let obj={
  'app': ['placementId'],
  'app2': ['siteId'],
  'app3': ['channel_id'],
};

function search(y){
 return Object.keys(obj).filter((x, id, arr)=> {
   if(x===y) {
   console.log(x,y); //gives out 'app app'
   console.log(obj[x]); //gives out [placementId]
   console.log(obj[x][0]); //gives out placementId
   return obj[y]
   }
  })
};

console.log(search('app')); //filter will only give that item (out of multiple), where conditions matched, so output is 'app' (in the item out of all, where condition matched);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because filter callback return boolean value to filter array. If you want find first by key it should be like that:

```
let obj={
  'app': ['placementId'],
  'app2': ['siteId'],
  'app3': ['channel_id'],
};
    
function search(y){
  return obj[Object.keys(obj).find((x)=> x === y)][0];
};
    
search('app');
```

No need to use filter function in this current case:

```
function search(y){
 return obj[y][0]
};
```